# How to define a textview surrounded by two images?

Tags: android

The textview should fill the space left by the images:

```
[imageview 40px, aligned left][textview][imageview 40px, aligned right]
```

This is my code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:src="@drawable/indicator_code_lock_point_area_green_holo"
        android:tag="heart" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:text="Shakespeare was a respected poet and playwright in his own day, but his reputation did not rise to its present heights until the 19th century." />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:src="@drawable/indicator_code_lock_point_area_green_holo"
        android:tag="heart" />

</LinearLayout>
```

As you can see the text takes over the image on the right.

Comment: Set android:layout_width="0dp" and  android:layout_weight="1" for your TextView.

Comment: It works great. Thanks nfirex. Can you post an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Also, if you will set android:id for your ImageViews you can use RelativeLayout instead of LinearLayout.

Comment: Seems like a valid question. Why does this question have negative votes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `LinearLayout` you just need to set `weight=1` and `width=0dp` for your `TextView`:

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:text="Shakespeare was a respected poet and playwright in his own day, but his reputation did not rise to its present heights until the 19th century." />
```

But if you don't set id for `ImageView`s and if your drawables for `ImageView` are not 9.png [answer of Anupam Majhi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16446595/1001401) is better (you don't need to use ImageView in that way).

Answer (score 0):

Use [drawableLeft](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3adrawableLeft) and [drawableRight](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3adrawableRight) attributes.

Answer (score 0):

In the XML write this for the text view

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_menu_call"
        android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/ic_menu_call"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:minHeight="100dp"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:text="Contacts"/>
```

Here,

```
android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_menu_call"
android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/ic_menu_call"
```

set the images

Comment: Thanks, I need ImageViews around the text, not drawables. See my code above.

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Your Text Goes Here" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: here basically the textview has been given a weight of 1 along with both the images to share the space..